# Removing every line that is not a sequence of 7 numbers

Tags: text-processing

I have a text file like this:

```
229;39;45;11;21;33;13
230;56;44;41;40;08;53
231;16;59;27;42;44;36
232;29;19;41;22;37;59
233;45;03;24;36;07;32
SP;SP;SP;;;;
234;15;45;54;25;42;41
235;29;41;55;02;31;22
236;10;52;50;57;25;60
237;36;07;45;31;56;57
238;15;09;41;13;37;42
SP;SP;;;;;
239;33;21;44;46;47;06
240;59;28;25;41;57;38
241;11;57;40;35;56;31
242;22;07;04;21;28;56
243;20;47;23;32;16;11
244;19;60;50;24;47;33
245;44;51;27;53;08;60
MG;;;;;;
```

The correct lines are a sequence of seven numbers separated by semi-colon. At random positions there are lines that are garbage, like `MG;;;;;;` or `SP;SP;;;;;`

What command should I type on terminal to remove these wrong lines from the file that contains thousands of lines, keeping just the lines that are sequences of seven numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep -Ex '[0-9]+(;[0-9]+){6}'
```

...produces the following output given your input data:

```
229;39;45;11;21;33;13
230;56;44;41;40;08;53
231;16;59;27;42;44;36
232;29;19;41;22;37;59
233;45;03;24;36;07;32
234;15;45;54;25;42;41
235;29;41;55;02;31;22
236;10;52;50;57;25;60
237;36;07;45;31;56;57
238;15;09;41;13;37;42
239;33;21;44;46;47;06
240;59;28;25;41;57;38
241;11;57;40;35;56;31
242;22;07;04;21;28;56
243;20;47;23;32;16;11
244;19;60;50;24;47;33
245;44;51;27;53;08;60
```

Comment: SIMPLY BRILLIANT! ! ! ! ! ! ! Thanks, you are a genius!

Comment: ahh, he just beat me to it! The only improvement I see (depending on your requirements) would be to anchor the pattern matching to the beginning and end of line, so that it catches lines containing the 7 semicoloned numbers *and only 7 semicoloned numbers* (omitting lines like "J1;2;3;4;5;6;7" or "1;2;3;4;5;6;7K"

Comment: @JeffSchaller - it is anchored - that's what `-x` does.

Comment: I learned something, too! Thanks @mikeserv!

Comment: +1, I'd like to suggest a little shorter pattern: `grep -Ex '([0-9]+;?){7}'`

Comment: @kos - I thought about it, but it is ambiguous. It will match a trailing `;`. Which is not to mention that it matches `0000000`

Comment: @mikeserv Good catch on the `0000000`, I didn't realize. Then I think you got the best pattern you could for the scope

Answer (score 2):

With `sed`:

```
sed -n '/^[0-9][0-9]*\(;[0-9][0-9]*\)\{6\}$/p' <infile
```

Comment: With `sed` you can use `s/pattern/&/[count]` for tests, too.

Comment: @mikeserv: We still must check for the first (or last if you use `[0-9];` sequence number, so using the check only can be easier.

Comment: Yeah, ok. Good point. Can't upvote you twice, though, I'm afraid.

Comment: +1, I'd like to add that using GNU `sed` one could use the `+` quantifier and avoid escaping parenthesis, shortening everything to `sed -rn '/^[0-9]+(;[0-9]+){6}$/p' <infile`

Comment: @kos - that also works w/ BSD `sed` if you use `-E`. And `-E` *also* works with GNU `sed` - and will soon be standardized by POSIX. So it might be worthwhile to drop the `-r` habit. I never understood what it was supposed to stand for, anyway.

Comment: @mikeserv: According to GNU doc, it's `r`egexp-extended.

Comment: So why not just use `-E` in the first place??? They're *all* regexps. It seems weird that they would neglect to put the most significant word in that description in the option-naming field...

Comment: @mikeserv: Yes, like everybody else, I don't know what the reason why they use that name. Personally, I never use it.

Comment: @mikeserv There's no `-E` option mentioned in my GNU `sed` manpage (GNU `sed` 4.4.2)

Comment: @kos - it's not documented, but it does work.

Comment: @mikeserv Indeed it does. Do you happen to know if it's fully functional? I can't see why it's not documented otherwise. I'm sure there's a good reason

Comment: @kos - it does everything `-r` does - they mean the same things. *(Only `-E` is better at meaning it)*.  There was one difference though that i recall reading about, but i dont remember what. Something about either E or r switching to and from BRE with an extra `-e`xpression statement. Whatever it was, it was insignificant.

Comment: @mikeserv Ok I see, thanks for the informations and for the `-E` trick, I had no idea about it. I find it more intuitive as well. I think I'll start using it in place of `-r` from now on!

Comment: So, to put it all together: `sed -E '/^[0-9]+(;[0-9]+){6}$/!d' <infile`

Answer (score 1):

`egrep '^[0-9]+;[0-9]+;[0-9]+;[0-9]+;[0-9]+;[0-9]+;[0-9]+$' file > temp && mv temp file`

Answer (score 1):

These are not as robust as some of the other examples, but will work for simple cases:

```sh
grep -v ';;'
```

Or

```sh
grep [[:digit:]]
```

Comment: When globbing is not disabled the second one will search only for a 9 if there is a file named *9* in the current directory.